# Is it possible to set up a file server with just a router

Tags: networking, router, file-server

I'm interested in setting up a file server somewhere where I don't have access to the internet.

Is it possible to do this with just an off the shelf router?

If anyone could point me in the right direction of the correct software or a guide on how to do this that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yeah, there are many routers nowadays with usb ports that you can plug in an external drive to act as a file server as well, such as Linksys E2000. you can just search for routers with usb port and find many more.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file server on pretty much any Local Area Network. Without an internet connection (most) consumer routers should still provide LAN connectivity without an actual internet connection.